# Mientras se agregan productos, cambiar de name los inputs que los contienen

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una práctica de carrito de compras, y cuando envío la lista de productos a gmail solo me aparece el último ya que el js aumenta el input con el mismo nombre.

Lo que quiero que haga es que mientas aumentan los productos también cambien el valor de `name=""`

Ejemplo
(producto uno) `name="productos"`
(producto dos) `name="productos2"` y así incrementado

```
leerLocalStorageCompra(){
    let productosLs;
    productosLs = this.obtenerProductosLocalStore();
    productosLs.forEach(function(producto){
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>
        <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="producto"  class="form-control" value="${producto.titulo}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="cantidad" class="form-control cantidad" min="1" value=${producto.cantidad}>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="borrar-producto fas fa-times-circle" style="font-size:30px" data-id="${producto.id}"></a>
    </td>
    
    
    
    
    
    `;
    listaCompra.appendChild(row);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le podrías enviar a la funcion leerLocalStorageCompra(nroItems) un entero con la cantidad de Items. Luego en el parámetro name lo asignas como en value con un literal:

```
<input type="text" name=`producto${nroItems}`  class="form-control" value=`${producto.titulo}` readonly>
```

También podrias tener una variable global con ese número.

Comment: gracias me funciono